# Arithmectic operator in c,modulus(%) giving warning. why?

Tags: c, operators

```
int main(void)
{
    int a=12,b=3;
    printf("\n a+b = %i\n",a+b);
    printf("\n a-b = %i\n",a-b);
    printf("\n a*b = %i\n",a*b);
    printf("\n a/b = %i\n",a/b);
    printf("\n a%b = %i\n",a%b);//conversion type error 
}
```

The modulus part is giving the warning as `Unknown conversion type character 'b' in format.`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is `printf` giving the warning, scape the modulus character with another modulus:

```
printf("\n a%%b = %i\n",a%b);
```

As you may see in the manual: [printf(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) there's no `b` flag character, so when `printf` find your `%b` in your string it doesn't know what to do. Since you don't want any formatting in that case, just include the `%` character in your string, you just need to scape the `%` character with another `%` character as in the example above.

Comment: Yes it's working now, but why this extra %?

Comment: Added a brief explanation and the reference to the manual page. Those are the semantics for printf :)

Comment: @Gopal In `%%` for the `printf(3)` function, the first `%` acts as an escape character for the second `%`. It tells `printf` that the character following the first `%` is not a "conversion type character", but an actual percent symbol.